# PHP/ODBC connection doesn't work without credentials

Tags: php, apache, odbc, mariadb

I am setting up a new server using...

- Debian9
- Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
- PHP Version 7.0.30-0+deb9u1
- MariaDB (mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB)
- unixODBC 2.3.4

I am trying to get this code segment which has run on previous versions to work...

```
<?php 
$connection = odbc_connect('pubassist', '', '');
if (!$connection) { exit("Connection Failed:" . odbc_errormsg() ); }
$sql = "select count(contact_no) as cCount from contact";
$result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
#   echo number_format(odbc_num_rows($result)) . " records were retrieved.";
    $contactCount = odbc_result($result, "cCount");
    echo number_format($contactCount) . " records were retrieved.";
}


odbc_close($conection);
?>
```

You'll note that the credentials are missing from the call to odbc_connect().  This is because I have included them in the DSN definition in /etc/odbc.ini...

```
[pubassist]
Driver=MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver
DATABASE=pubassist
DESCRIPTION=PubAssist via ODBC
SERVER=127.0.0.1
USER=<myuser>
PASSWORD=<myuserpassword>
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#PORT=3306
```

Apparently Apache and PHP are attempting to connect to the ODBC data source using Apache's credentials.  I get the following error message:

> Connection Failed:[unixODBC][ma-3.0.7]Access denied for user
>   'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Of course the connection works if I provide valid credentials.  I have worked on similar applications and find it beneficial to keep all credentials in odbc.ini and keep that file properly protected.  As I said, this technique has worked in previous LAMP installations.

I know this is similar to questions already posted.  I have been pouring through these for days now.  I understand why the user id 'www-data' has been submitted, but I have not found a way to make this connection *without providing the credentials in the code*.

By the way, the 'pubassist' DSN has been verified using iSQL.  Also, if I provide the credentials, the response I get from this page shows that I can indeed connect to the database and gather the requested records...

> Testing ODBC This page connects to an ODBC DSN.
>
> If successful, a message for the number of records retrieved will be
>   presented. If not, an error message will be presented.
>
> 3,237 records were retrieved.

Furthermore, I have tried changing the parameters in the call to odbc_connection().  The empty string parameters have worked in the past.  Changing the empty strings to NULL has no effect.  Removing the quotes generates a syntax error.  Eliminating the empty parameters causes a PHP error because 3 parameters are required.

***I think I'm looking for an Apache or PHP configuration setting that will allow the connection to be made without specifying the credentials.  But, any insight would be most welcome.***

One last thing:  This is my first post.  I have been coding and debugging for years.  More and more, the answers I seek are found on StackOverflow.  This has been an incredibly valuable resource.  Just wanted to share that along with asking for help.

Thanks in advance,

Ron

Comment: I should also add that I've tried changing a few things in odbc.ini.  Here's the original version of the DSN definition:

    `[pubassist]
Driver=MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver
DATABASE=pubassist
DESCRIPTION=PubAssist via ODBC
    SERVER=localhost
    USER=<myuser>
    PASSWORD=<myuserpassword>
    socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    PORT=3306`

Comment: I've been scouring the web for an answer.  One new bit of information is that it seems that Apache will ALWAYS try to log in using it's own credentials--if no other credentials are provided.  That's different from looking for the credentials in the ODBC data source definition.  So, one thing I have been able to do to make this work has been to create the mysql user using the same account name as the Apache user.

Still looking for a better solution.